# Importing files into SQLite database not using all cores

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, sqlite, task

### Context

I am importing IMDB database files into an SQLite database with the help of EntityFrameworkCore. In fact, two files, the titles.basics and the titles.akas (which is linked to basics via its movie ID).

At first, I had a single thread reading lines from basics and loop through akas until it changes of ID. Though, there was an issue there and most of all, it was too slow. So, I decided to create a multithread code that would read both files at the same time and another combining akas with the appropriate movie.

I am currently importing so I still do not know if my issue is fixed (probably it is). Though, it is still too much slow for me.

### Issue

The **combining** part is still very slow, but more importantly, I can see my process is only using around 12% of CPU which corresponds to only 1/8 of total usage and I have 8 physical cores. So, it really seems the process is only using 1 core.

I am not giving any code here, as having a minimal testable code wouldn't mean anything. Though, you can see both versions here:

https://cints.net/public/Imdb-MultiThread.cs.txt

```
using com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.Database;
using com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.Models.Metas;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.MetaSources
{
    class Imdb : MediaSource
    {
        private const string TITLES_FILE = "title.basics.tsv.gz";
        private const string AKAS_FILE = "title.akas.tsv.gz";
        private readonly string temporaryFolder = @"c:\temp\";
        private readonly string baseUrl = "https://datasets.imdbws.com/";
        private readonly WebClient webClient = new();

        MediaRecognizerContext db = new();

        private IQueryable<MetaMovie> imdbMovies = null;

        private async Task<bool> GatherFilesAsync()
        {
            var totalFilesGathered = 0;
            var filesToDownload = new string[] { AKAS_FILE, TITLES_FILE };
            foreach(var fileToDownload in filesToDownload)
            {
                var compressedFile = temporaryFolder + fileToDownload;
                if (!File.Exists(compressedFile) || !File.GetLastWriteTime(compressedFile).Date.Equals(DateTime.Today))
                {
                    await GatherFileAsync(fileToDownload);
                    totalFilesGathered++;
                }
            }

            return totalFilesGathered != 0;
        }

        private async Task GatherFileAsync(string fileName)
        {
            var compressedFile = temporaryFolder + fileName;
            var uncompressedFile = temporaryFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(compressedFile);
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(baseUrl + fileName, compressedFile);

            using Stream fd = File.Create(uncompressedFile);
            using Stream fs = File.OpenRead(compressedFile);
            using Stream csStream = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            int nRead;
            while ((nRead = await csStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                await fd.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, nRead);
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadMetaDataAsync()
        {
            //return; //TODO: Remove this line

            //TODO: Reactivate this line
            //if (!await GatherFilesAsync()) return;


            var titlesFile = temporaryFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TITLES_FILE);
            var akasFile = temporaryFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AKAS_FILE);
            var dbLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            var akasLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            var currentTitlesAkasLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            var associateLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

            using (var db = new MediaRecognizerContext())
            {
                db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                var titles = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MetaMovie>();
                var readTitles = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(titlesFile), (titleLine, _, readingIndex) =>
                    {
                        if (readingIndex == 0) return; // Skipping columns titles line

                        var movieInfos = titleLine.Split("\t", StringSplitOptions.None);
                        dbLock.Wait();
                        MetaMovie metaMovie = db.MetaMovies.Where(m => m.ExternalId == movieInfos[0]).Include(m => m.Titles).FirstOrDefault();
                        dbLock.Release();
                        if (metaMovie == null)
                        {
                            int totalMinutes = -1;
                            if (!int.TryParse(movieInfos[7], out totalMinutes))
                            {
                                totalMinutes = -1;
                            }
                            metaMovie = new MetaMovie
                            {
                                ExternalId = movieInfos[0],
                                MetaSource = nameof(Imdb),
                                MovieType = movieInfos[1],
                                Title = movieInfos[3],
                                TotalMinutes = totalMinutes,
                                Genres = movieInfos[8]
                            };
                            metaMovie.Titles = new List<MetaTitle>();
                            if (int.TryParse(movieInfos[5], out int startYear))
                            {
                                metaMovie.StartYear = new DateTime(startYear, 1, 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                metaMovie.StartYear = new DateTime(9999, 1, 1);
                            }
                            if (int.TryParse(movieInfos[6], out int endYear))
                            {
                                metaMovie.EndYear = new DateTime(endYear, 1, 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                metaMovie.EndYear = metaMovie.StartYear;
                            }
                        }

                        titles.TryAdd(metaMovie.ExternalId, metaMovie);
                    });
                });

                var akas = new Dictionary<string, List<MetaTitle>>();
                var currentTitlesAkas = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
                var readAkas = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(akasFile), (akaLine, _, readingIndex) =>
                    {
                        if (readingIndex == 0) return; // Skipping columns titles line

                        currentTitlesAkasLock.Wait();
                        var titleInfos = akaLine.Split("\t", StringSplitOptions.None);
                        var externalId = titleInfos[0];
                        if (!currentTitlesAkas.ContainsKey(externalId))
                        {
                            currentTitlesAkas.TryAdd(externalId, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentTitlesAkas[externalId]++;
                        }
                        currentTitlesAkasLock.Release();

                        var metaTitle = new MetaTitle
                        {
                            MetaMovie = null,
                            Text = titleInfos[2],
                            Region = titleInfos[3],
                            Language = titleInfos[4]
                        };

                        akasLock.Wait();
                        List<MetaTitle> titleAkas;
                        if (!akas.ContainsKey(externalId))
                        {
                            titleAkas = new List<MetaTitle>();
                            akas.Add(externalId, titleAkas);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            titleAkas = akas[externalId];
                        }
                        titleAkas.Add(metaTitle);
                        akasLock.Release();

                        currentTitlesAkasLock.Wait();
                        currentTitlesAkas[externalId]--;
                        currentTitlesAkasLock.Release();
                    });
                });

                var savingCounter = 0;
                var associate = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.For(1, Environment.ProcessorCount * 10, async (_) =>
                    {
                        var isAssociating = true;
                        do
                        {
                            var externalId = string.Empty;
                            var currentTitleAkaRemoved = false;
                            currentTitlesAkasLock.Wait();
                            foreach (var curExternalId in currentTitlesAkas.Keys.OrderBy(t => t))
                            {
                                if (currentTitlesAkas[curExternalId] == 0)
                                {
                                    externalId = curExternalId;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (externalId != String.Empty)
                            {
                                currentTitleAkaRemoved = currentTitlesAkas.TryRemove(externalId, out int useless0); // Removing so other threads won't take it
                            }
                            isAssociating = !readAkas.IsCompleted || !readTitles.IsCompleted || !currentTitlesAkas.IsEmpty;
                            currentTitlesAkasLock.Release();

                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(externalId) || !currentTitleAkaRemoved) continue;

                            if (titles.TryGetValue(externalId, out MetaMovie metaMovie))
                            {
                                akasLock.Wait();
                                var titleAkas = akas[externalId];
                                akas.Remove(externalId);
                                akasLock.Release();

                                var changedMovie = false;
                                var movieAkas = metaMovie.Titles.Select(t => t).ToList(); // Clone list
                                foreach (var metaTitle in titleAkas)
                                {
                                    var existingTitle = movieAkas.Where(t => t.Text == metaTitle.Text && t.Region == metaTitle.Region && t.Language == metaTitle.Language).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (existingTitle == null)
                                    {
                                        changedMovie = true;
                                        metaMovie.Titles.Add(metaTitle);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        movieAkas.Remove(existingTitle);
                                    }
                                }
                                foreach (var movieTitle in movieAkas)
                                {
                                    changedMovie = true;
                                    metaMovie.Titles.Remove(movieTitle);
                                }

                                dbLock.Wait();
                                if (metaMovie.Id == 0)
                                {
                                    db.Add(metaMovie);
                                }
                                else if (changedMovie)
                                {
                                    db.Update(metaMovie);
                                }
                                dbLock.Release();

                                currentTitlesAkasLock.Wait();
                                currentTitlesAkas.TryRemove(externalId, out int uselessOut); // Free memory
                                isAssociating = !readAkas.IsCompleted || !readTitles.IsCompleted || !currentTitlesAkas.IsEmpty;
                                currentTitlesAkasLock.Release();

                                titles.TryRemove(externalId, out MetaMovie uselessOut2); // Free memory

                                associateLock.Wait();
                                savingCounter++;
                                var localSavingCounter = savingCounter;
                                associateLock.Release();

                                if (localSavingCounter != 0 && localSavingCounter % 1000 == 0)
                                {
                                    var ttt = currentTitlesAkas.Where(t => t.Value > 0);
                                    dbLock.Wait();
                                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                                    dbLock.Release();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Saved " + localSavingCounter);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (!readTitles.IsCompleted) // If reading titles is not ended, then maybe it was not read yet... otherwise, it doesn't exist
                            {
                                currentTitlesAkasLock.Wait();
                                currentTitlesAkas.TryAdd(externalId, 0); // Readd because still no movie associated
                                currentTitlesAkasLock.Release();
                            }
                        } while (isAssociating);
                    });
                });

                Task.WaitAll(readTitles, readAkas, associate);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async override Task<IEnumerable<MetaMovie>> FindMediasAsync(DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            await LoadMetaDataAsync();

            var movie = await ExtractInfosAsync(directory);
            if (movie == null) return null;

            if (imdbMovies == null)
            {
                imdbMovies = db.MetaMovies.Where(m => m.MetaSource == nameof(Imdb) && m.MovieType == "movie");
            }

            return FindCorrespondances(imdbMovies, movie);
        }
    }
}
```

https://cints.net/public/Imdb-SingleThread.cs.txt

```
using com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.Database;
using com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.Models.Metas;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace com.cyberinternauts.all.MediaRecognizer.MetaSources
{
    class Imdb : MediaSource
    {
        private const string TITLES_FILE = "title.basics.tsv.gz";
        private const string AKAS_FILE = "title.akas.tsv.gz";
        private readonly string temporaryFolder = @"c:\temp\";
        private readonly string baseUrl = "https://datasets.imdbws.com/";
        private readonly WebClient webClient = new();

        MediaRecognizerContext db = new();

        private IQueryable<MetaMovie> imdbMovies = null;

        private async Task<bool> GatherFilesAsync()
        {
            var totalFilesGathered = 0;
            var filesToDownload = new string[] { AKAS_FILE, TITLES_FILE };
            foreach(var fileToDownload in filesToDownload)
            {
                var compressedFile = temporaryFolder + fileToDownload;
                if (!File.Exists(compressedFile) || !File.GetLastWriteTime(compressedFile).Date.Equals(DateTime.Today))
                {
                    await GatherFileAsync(fileToDownload);
                    totalFilesGathered++;
                }
            }

            return totalFilesGathered != 0;
        }

        private async Task GatherFileAsync(string fileName)
        {
            var compressedFile = temporaryFolder + fileName;
            var uncompressedFile = temporaryFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(compressedFile);
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(baseUrl + fileName, compressedFile);

            using Stream fd = File.Create(uncompressedFile);
            using Stream fs = File.OpenRead(compressedFile);
            using Stream csStream = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            int nRead;
            while ((nRead = await csStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                await fd.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, nRead);
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadMetaDataAsync()
        {
            //return; //TODO: Remove this line

            //TODO: Reactivate this line
            //if (!await GatherFilesAsync()) return;

            var titlesFile = temporaryFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TITLES_FILE);
            var akasFile = temporaryFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AKAS_FILE);
            var titlesLines = File.ReadLines(titlesFile);
            var akasLines = File.ReadLines(akasFile);


            var titlesIterator = titlesLines.GetEnumerator();
            titlesIterator.MoveNext(); // Skip columns headers

            var akasIterator = akasLines.GetEnumerator();
            akasIterator.MoveNext();
            akasIterator.MoveNext(); // Done twice to skip columns headers
            var currentAka = akasIterator.Current;
            var savingCounter = 0;

            using (var db = new MediaRecognizerContext())
            {
                db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                while (titlesIterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var titleLine = titlesIterator.Current;
                    var movieInfos = titleLine.Split("\t", StringSplitOptions.None);
                    MetaMovie metaMovie = db.MetaMovies.Where(m => m.ExternalId == movieInfos[0]).FirstOrDefault();
                    var isNewMovie = false;
                    if (metaMovie == null)
                    {
                        int totalMinutes = -1;
                        if (!int.TryParse(movieInfos[7], out totalMinutes))
                        {
                            totalMinutes = -1;
                        }
                        isNewMovie = true;
                        metaMovie = new MetaMovie
                        {
                            ExternalId = movieInfos[0],
                            MetaSource = nameof(Imdb),
                            MovieType = movieInfos[1],
                            Title = movieInfos[3],
                            TotalMinutes = totalMinutes,
                            Genres = movieInfos[8]
                        };
                        metaMovie.Titles = new List<MetaTitle>();
                        if (int.TryParse(movieInfos[5], out int startYear))
                        {
                            metaMovie.StartYear = new DateTime(startYear, 1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            metaMovie.StartYear = new DateTime(9999, 1, 1);
                        }
                        if (int.TryParse(movieInfos[6], out int endYear))
                        {
                            metaMovie.EndYear = new DateTime(endYear, 1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            metaMovie.EndYear = metaMovie.StartYear;
                        }
                    }

                    var movieAkasIds = metaMovie.Titles.Select(t => t.Id).ToList();
                    var titleInfos = currentAka?.Split("\t", StringSplitOptions.None);
                    while (currentAka != null && int.Parse(titleInfos[0][2..]) <= int.Parse(metaMovie.ExternalId[2..]))
                    {
                        if (titleInfos[0] == metaMovie.ExternalId)
                        {
                            var metaTitle = new MetaTitle
                            {
                                MetaMovie = metaMovie,
                                Text = titleInfos[2],
                                Region = titleInfos[3],
                                Language = titleInfos[4]
                            };

                            var existingTitle = metaMovie.Titles.Where(t => t.Text == metaTitle.Text && t.Region == metaTitle.Region && t.Language == metaTitle.Language).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (existingTitle == null)
                            {
                                metaMovie.Titles.Add(metaTitle);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                movieAkasIds.Remove(existingTitle.Id);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var a = 1;
                        }

                        akasIterator.MoveNext();
                        currentAka = akasIterator.Current;
                        titleInfos = currentAka.Split("\t", StringSplitOptions.None);
                    }

                    foreach(var movieTitleId in movieAkasIds)
                    {
                        metaMovie.Titles.Remove(metaMovie.Titles.Where(t => t.Id == movieTitleId).FirstOrDefault());
                    }

                    if (isNewMovie)
                    {
                        db.Add(metaMovie);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Update(metaMovie);
                    }

                    savingCounter++;
                    if (savingCounter % 10000 == 0)
                    {
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine("Saved " + savingCounter);
                    }
                }

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async override Task<IEnumerable<MetaMovie>> FindMediasAsync(DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            await LoadMetaDataAsync();

            var movie = await ExtractInfosAsync(directory);
            if (movie == null) return null;

            if (imdbMovies == null)
            {
                imdbMovies = db.MetaMovies.Where(m => m.MetaSource == nameof(Imdb) && m.MovieType == "movie");
            }

            return FindCorrespondances(imdbMovies, movie);
        }
    }
}
```

In the multithread version, the slow part is in the method `LoadMetaDataAsync` and more precisely in `var associate = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>` code part.

This is in development and cleaning, splitting will done after I have the appropriate result/speed.

Comment: A profiler would probably tell you why you are not getting the results expected. Either there is resource contention, or you are not actually starting the number of threads you expect.

Comment: so that tells you that you are io bound, I dont know EF but I know SQLite very well, you are sure you are batching up writes into large commit blocks?

Comment: @pm100 I am using `db.SaveChangesAsync` only when 1000 records where added or modified.

Comment: @FrankHileman Yes, I could use a profiler, but I think it can be resolved without it, and even though I already used some, it makes a while. Concerning the number of threads, in the *combining* part you can see `Parallel.For(1, Environment.ProcessorCount * 10, async (_) =>`. I first not multiply by 10, but I added it to ensure there were enough threads to be spawned over all my cores.

Comment: You might consider using [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-6.0) instead of SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: If you don't want to use a profiler, you could at least check the thread id of each task to ensure you do have threads (but managed threads are not the same as hardware threads, hence the need for a profiler). If you ensure you have threads running, then they are either blocked, or it was never a CPU bound problem to start with.

Comment: I notice that in `GatherFileAsync` the buffer is 1024 *bytes*. Have you tried with a larger buffer, perhaps 32768?

Comment: @Odrai I may consider this, but all the threads are Readers and Writers.

Comment: @AndrewMorton For now, the GatherFileAsync is not called. I am using the currently downloaded file to test the importation part called `LoadMetaDataAsync`. So it is not related the to issue. But I'll take a note to change it after importation part is OK.

Comment: It doesn't appear that anyone has made the comment yet, but threads are good for CPU intensive operations with ***very little disk I/O***. You're doing the opposite. It's far more likely that an optimized single-threaded app will be faster.

Comment: @MasterDJon - It would also be great to get a [mcve]. When I copy and paste your code I get a lot of errors.

Comment: @Enigmativity I extracted the part tested here (there is only the multithread version) and created a new public repo for it: https://github.com/djon2003/mediarecognizer_test

Comment: @Enigmativity And yes, I am really starting to think this part of the software won't be multithreaded, but in case we could figure out the issue here, it may also be applicable for the single thread version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed. I returned to the single thread version and I found my initial issue (my code was supposing the files were in order, which they were partially).

Thank you for all people that participated.